# Can not access private members of class (C++)

Tags: c++, list, class, struct

I developed a solution in c++ that is using linked lists. First, I used `struct` to create my list and the nodes (which worked perfectly), but now I am required to have Data private so i am now using `classes` instead.
I can not access the private members of my two classes.

Here is my node class

```
class node{                                                         //class for a node  ;
        private:
            int info;
            class node *next;
        public:
            node();
            node(int info1,node myNode){
                info1 = info;
                *next = myNode;
            }
    };
    typedef class node Node;                                        //the new class called Node
```

Here is my list class

```
    class mylist{                                                       //class for a list   ;
    private:
        Node *head;
        Node *tail;
    public:
        mylist();
        mylist(node a, node b){
        *head = a;
        *tail = b;
        }
        node getHead(){
            return *head;
        }
        node getTail(){
            return *tail;
        }
};
typedef class mylist Tlist;                                        //the new class called Tlist
```

Here is the function from which I am trying to access members of a class:

```
int isEmpty(Tlist l){
    /** Return true if the head of the list is NULL and false otherwise **/
    return getHead(l.head) == NULL;   //error occurs for this line ('Node mylist::head' is private within this content)
}
```

Comment: Make the function a member of your class.

Comment: Or a `friend` of your class.

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing the empty check as a free function. This function does not have access to the private members.

Two possible solutions:

First is free function using public members (usage: `isEmpty(l)`):

```
bool isEmpty(Tlist l){
    /** Return true if the head of the list is NULL and false otherwise **/
    return l.getHead() == nullptr;   //error occurs for this line ('Node mylist::head' is private within this content)
}
```

Second is a member function (usage: `l.isEmpty()`):

```
class mylist {
public:
    bool isEmpty(){
        /** Return true if the head of the list is NULL and false otherwise **/
        return head == nullptr;   //error occurs for this line ('Node mylist::head' is private within this content)
    }
}
```

Please note that I changed `NULL` (C style) to `nullptr` and the return value from `int` to `bool`. Your body of the function looked strange too, so I changed it to what seems more appropriate.

Comment: I tried the second solution- making isEmpty() a member function of class `mylist` but now when I call it by `isEmpty(L);` i get " 'isEmpty' was not declared in this scope" error.
I also tried calling it by `mylist::isEmpty(L);` but then I get "no matching function for call to 'mylist::isEmpty(Tlist&)' " error.

Comment: @AlinSalagean I updated my answer. Member functions are not called as `fun(object)` but as `object.fun()`. You have made that same error in your original implementation of `isEmpty`. You can compare my changes to your implementation.

Comment: thank you for your edit, I am now calling it as `L.isEmpty()` and I am back to my first issue. I get the "... is private within this context".

Comment: @AlinSalagean Where do you get the error? You need to make `isEmpty` member function public if you want to access it from outside the class (I updated my code to reflect that).